# ffmpeg: MPEG-TS file always starting at 1.4 seconds

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to convert an MPEG file into an MPEG-TS file. However, when I do so, it always starts at 1.422456 seconds.

[image: start: 1.422456]

I'm bothered by this, as I'm trying to create an M3U that uses `#EXTM3U`. No matter what I do, including `-output_ts_offset 0` and `-copyts -start_at_zero`, it won't simply go back to 0. What else can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `-muxpreload 0 -muxdelay 0` to remove the 1.4 seconds offset. It may not get exactly zero, depending on if video codec has a delay.

Answer (score 2):

This is very normal for TS. TS was designed for broadcast television, it was designed to have an infinite run time (taking into account integer overflows) where viewers will join and leave randomly. It bothers me a clock starts at 12am and not zero. But that’s the way it is. It normal, it’s expected and it’s convention for many historical and mathematical reasons. And even though it bothers me, it is correct.